# Drag and Drop Iframe - Javascript & CSS

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, drag

I have a Chrome extension with an iframe inside of it. I want the iframe to be draggable from left to right only. The following code I have provided allows for this and stores the location of the iframe for loading the page but it only allows the iframe to move when the cursor is outside of the document making for a poor user experience. How do I alter the code so that the iframe moves when the cursor is dragging it whilst the cursor is located both outside the iframe or inside(hovering over) the iframe.

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = 'firebase-extension-iframe';
iframe.src = 'about:blank';
let storedPosition = { x: null, y: null };

chrome.storage.local.get(['iframePosition'], result => {
  storedPosition = result.iframePosition || storedPosition;
  let isDragging = false;
  let initialMouseX = 0;
  let initialIframeX = 0;

  iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
  iframe.style.bottom = storedPosition.y || '0'; // Use stored position or default value
  iframe.style.right = storedPosition.x || '50px'; // Use stored position or default value
  iframe.style.width = '350px';
  iframe.style.height = '500px';
  iframe.style.border = 'none';
  iframe.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  iframe.style.zIndex = '9999';
  iframe.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  iframe.style.borderTopLeftRadius = '10px'; // Rounded upper left corner
  iframe.style.borderTopRightRadius = '10px'; // Rounded upper right corner
  iframe.style.border = '1px solid red';
  iframe.style.cursor = 'ew-resize'; // Change cursor to indicate draggable element

  const startDrag = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const target = event.target;
    if (target === iframe) {
      isDragging = true;
      initialMouseX = event.clientX;
      initialIframeX = parseFloat(iframe.style.right) || 0;

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragIframe);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
    }
  };

  const dragIframe = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDragging) {
      const offsetX = event.clientX - initialMouseX;
      const newIframeX = initialIframeX - offsetX;
      iframe.style.right = `${Math.max(0, newIframeX)}px`;
    }
  };

  const stopDrag = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDragging) {
      isDragging = false;
      storedPosition = {
        x: iframe.style.right,
        y: iframe.style.bottom
      };
      chrome.storage.local.set({ iframePosition: storedPosition });
    }
  };

  iframe.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```